# single quote in column name: SQL expression working fine in SQL Developer but failing in PowerBI

Tags: sql, powerbi

I do have a piece of SQL code that gave me some problems. The pivot operation results in a table with a column name called `'INITIAL'` which has the single quotes in the name. But the values in that column are integers, or NULLs. I managed to access the numbers in SQL developer by enclosing the column name with double quotes:  `"'INITIAL'"`. When copying the code to PowerBI, it is not accepted. I returns a

> Expression.SyntaxError: Token Comma expected

at the location of the first use of the single quote.
Any idea how to fix this for powerBI?

```
 PIVOT (
        SUM(conversion) 
    FOR PHASE 
    IN ('INITIAL')
   ))  
SELECT REQUEST, SUM("'INITIAL'")

FROM Pivoted

WHERE 'INITIAL' IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY REQUEST
```

Comment: Rename the column.

Answer (score 0):

To escape a character you need to use double quotation ("") mark. Please try this:

```
 PIVOT (
        SUM(conversion) 
    FOR PHASE 
    IN ('INITIAL')
   ))  
SELECT REQUEST, SUM(""'INITIAL'"")

FROM Pivoted

WHERE 'INITIAL' IS NOT NULL

GROUP BY REQUEST
```

Answer (score 0):

that nearly did the trick. I misread your post and used this:

SUM(""'02_INITIAL'"")

And that works in PowerBI!

So in SQL Developer I need to use SUM("'INITIAL'")

Best is fo course to avoid quotes in column names, but since my Pivot is based on string values, I get them for free.

Many thanks for your suggestion that put me on the right track!